# Form disappears when trying to create a shortcut VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wsh

When my code reaches the `Dim MyShortcut...` line the form disappears, no exception no windows error reporting the form just vanishes with the process still running.

```
Friend Sub CreateShortcut(Location As String, Target As String)
    Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut = CType((New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShellClass).CreateShortcut(Location), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)
    MyShortcut.TargetPath = Target
    MyShortcut.Save()
End Sub
```

Please ask if you need any more details. I wasn't sure what could be causing the issue so didn't know what else to add.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: when you say disappears, does this mean visual studio remains in debug mode or does it return to edit mode?

Comment: What's up the call stack? In other words, what's calling `CreateShortcut`?

Comment: When I say the form disappears Visual Studio does remain in debug mode

Comment: What calls the function does not have an effect, ie. what ever calls `CreateShortcut` the form still disappears. But it is being called on `PropertyChanged` event in `My.Settings` and also in one other place from another form.

Comment: I didn't know what else would be pertinent to the question as I cannot see an obvious starting point for solving this. If you can suggest what else I should add I would be glad to do so.